# IList<T> to IQueryable<T>

Tags: linq-to-objects, iqueryable

I have an List and I'd like to wrap it into an IQueryable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, };
IQueryable<int> query = list.AsQueryable();
```

If you don't see the `AsQueryable()` method, add a using statement for `System.Linq`.

Comment: If you interested in the long way you could do: from q in query select q or list.Select(q => q) both would also get you an IQueryable<T>

Answer (score 12):

Use the `AsQueryable<T>()` extension method.

Comment: is it an expensive operation? AsQueryable on List ?