# How change List<T> data to IQueryable<T> data

Tags: .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IList<T> to IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542/ilistt-to-iqueryablet)

I have a List data, but I want a IQueryable data , is it possible from  List data to IQueryable data?
Show me code

Answer (score 498, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string>();
var queryable = list.AsQueryable();
```

Add a reference to: `System.Linq`

Comment: Yes, definitely NOT `.ToQueryable()` which, silly me, kept thinking is what it would, if not should be.

:facepalm: