# Create IQueryable of Unknown Type from IList at Runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, iqueryable

I have an IList of Type Entity.

I have a string representing the Type of a class derived from Entity.

I need to cast my IList to IQueryable of the Type derived from Entity using the string.

Sadly, the assembly for Entity and derived classes is not the executing assembly.

Comment: Can you just call `.AsQueryable()`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542/ilistt-to-iqueryablet

Comment: I need it to be of a type derived from Entity that is not known at run time.

Comment: I may be missing something but If it is not known at run time how can this be even possible? How can an object be created from a type that is not available to the environment?

Comment: @nerdperson You need to be more concise. Is IList or `IList<Entity>`? The whole string "representing the Type" is the assembly qualified name of the type (i.e. "namespace.type, assembly")?

Comment: your list instance is IList or IList<Entity>?

Comment: @nerdperson ... ? We're not wizards. Please rephrase your question in order to let us understand what you're looking for. Thanks!

Comment: nevermind, pls tell us more about "derived from Entity"

Comment: I have IList<Entity>, I need IQueryable<CompanyProfile> or other unknown at runtime child class of Entity. I have the string name of CompanyProfile or other child class.  I need to use Dynamic Linq library on the IList, but System.Linq.Dynamic wants IQueryable - and I need to cast to the unknown child type at runtime because I am using a dynamic linq select query - so If I just use the Entity, I get an error, CompanyProfileId is not a column or property of Entity...

Comment: FYI I am trying to work within someone else's framework...

Comment: You need to give more information, I don't think you know what you want to do.  You're trying to query a collection of unknown types based on unknown values in order to... do unknown operations on said unknown types?  What?

Comment: I have already done this using a switch statement where i cast the ilist to the derived type then use asqueryable and use dynamic linq select statement on the iqueryable.

Comment: i would rather use reflection than the switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more information, this is the only thing I can think of that might be what you want.

```
var queryable = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var entity in IList<Entity>)
{
    dynamic companyProfile = Convert.ChangeType(entity, Type.GetType(typeString));
    if (companyProfile.CompanyProfileId == "something")
        queryable.Add(companyProfile);
    // Do Stuff
}
// Do Stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach with dynamic linq and reflection

```
var list = new List<Company>()
{
    new Company { Foo = "1", NoEmployees = 1 },
    new Company { Foo = "3", NoEmployees = 3 }
};

MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "AsQueryable" && x.IsGenericMethod).First();
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { Type.GetType(typeString) });

var queryable = (IQueryable)generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { list });

var result = queryable.Select("new (NoEmployees)").Where("NoEmployees > 2").OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Pls be more explicit next time

Comment: the section  "var result = queryable.Select("new (NoEmployees)").Where("NoEmployees > 2").OfType<object>().ToList();" does not compile? @alexb

Comment: how is it possible to pass a string as a predicate and then it gets evaluated and executed, all happening dynamically?

Comment: Thank you @alexb, do you not think your answer should also have been "more explicit"? lol

Comment: yes, I suppose :). although I think dynamic linq library is pretty popular, but maybe it's just my opinion